# mach_vm_protect unable to make memory executable

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to allocate memory dynamically and have it be executable through mach_vm_protect; however any time I try to execute the code the application crashes. But mach_vm_protect succeeds which is what I don't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/vm_map.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>

int test(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
typedef int (*test_mach_copy)(int,int);
#define CODE_SIZE 0x17
int main()
{

    
    mach_vm_address_t remoteCode64 = (vm_address_t) NULL;
    mach_vm_address_t testvmaddr = (vm_address_t)&test;
    task_t remotetask;
    task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), getpid(), &remotetask);
    if (mach_vm_protect(remotetask, testvmaddr, CODE_SIZE, 1, VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_EXECUTE)!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }
      
    if(mach_vm_allocate(remotetask,&remoteCode64,CODE_SIZE,VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE)!=KERN_SUCCESS){
        return 1;
    }
    if (mach_vm_protect(remotetask, remoteCode64, CODE_SIZE, 1, VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_EXECUTE|VM_PROT_WRITE|VM_PROT_COPY)!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }
    mach_vm_copy(remotetask, testvmaddr, CODE_SIZE, remoteCode64);
    test_mach_copy tmc = (test_mach_copy)remoteCode64;
    int x = tmc(10,20);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

x017 Is size the correct sizeof(test())

Comment: Some operating systems will not honor a Write + Execute permission on a page (even if the OS honors it, the architecture may reject it as well). Can you try making the page writeable (but not executable), perform the `memcpy`, then call `vm_protect` again to make it executable but not writeable.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR That's a very good idea. I"ll try that. But I would have imagined mach_vm_protect would fail in such cases.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by making 2 calls. There might be a bug in the kernel (or the runtime library) as it really does not return an error when you pass bad permissions.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for mentioning that. Do you also know if it's possible to set .text section permissions to writable? I Know I can set them to read but for some reason write causes them to fail. And I think its' because of what you mentioned. It already has execution privilege. So in order to write to it, I have to remove the execution privilege, set write privilege, write my data then set exection privilege again.

Comment: Right, but be careful that the code that is currently executing is not in the same `.text` segment that you're trying to modify or you'll just protect yourself into a page fault :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably your use of `VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_EXECUTE|VM_PROT_WRITE|VM_PROT_COPY`. Modern operating systems, and architectures, try to enforce `W^X` permissions. That is, either a memory range is executable or writeable, but never both.

There might be a bug in the kernel since your call to `mach_vm_protect` is returning `KERN_SUCCESS`.

I was able to get your code working by simply making 2 calls to `mach_vm_protect` in succession:

```
int main()
{
    mach_vm_address_t remoteCode64 = (vm_address_t) NULL;
    mach_vm_address_t testvmaddr = (vm_address_t)&test;
    task_t remotetask;
    task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), getpid(), &remotetask);
    if (mach_vm_protect(remotetask, testvmaddr, CODE_SIZE, 1, VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_EXECUTE)!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }

    if(mach_vm_allocate(remotetask,&remoteCode64,CODE_SIZE,VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE)!=KERN_SUCCESS){
      return 1;
    }

    if (mach_vm_protect(remotetask, remoteCode64, CODE_SIZE, 0, VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_WRITE|VM_PROT_COPY)!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (mach_vm_copy(remotetask, testvmaddr, CODE_SIZE, remoteCode64) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (mach_vm_protect(remotetask, remoteCode64, CODE_SIZE, 0, VM_PROT_READ|VM_PROT_EXECUTE)!=KERN_SUCCESS) {
      return 1;
    }
    test_mach_copy tmc = (test_mach_copy)remoteCode64;
    int x = tmc(10,20);
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Yuumi, when I was implementing virtual memory code for an OS I worked on, the MMU did not support an "execute-only" permission, i.e. execute without read. They must have ran into the same thing and just return an error in case a user tries it.

Comment: A vm was actually what I was working on too! That makes a lot of sense.